# VBA error handling (INDEX/MATCH in Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, exception, excel-formula, office365

In Excel one can lookup a value from a range using INDEX and MATCH functions;

[image]

the following expression is usually used:

```
=INDEX(tablerange,MATCH(rowval,col1range,0),MATCH(colval,row1range,0))
```

However, since I need this functionality very often I created my own simple custom VBA function `TabVal()` which returns a value from given range according to given values from heading column/row:

```
Public Function TabVal(t As Range, r As Range, c As Range)
Dim x, y As Integer
On Error GoTo ERROR
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(r.Cells(1, 1).Value, t.Columns(1), 0)
    y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(c.Cells(1, 1).Value, t.Rows(1), 0)
    TabVal = t.Cells(x, y).Value
    Exit Function
ERROR:
    TabVal = ""
End Function
```

This can be useful to somebody else. But is there any better error handling approach in VBA instead of `GoTo ERROR` (label)?

Comment: Use `Application.Match` and test if the result is an error using `IsError`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `Index` here at all: `TabVal = t.Cells(x, y).Value`.

Comment: `Dim x As Variant, y As Variant` if you use `Application.Match`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, just thought that Index() is not even needed. However I'd like to have syntax like `If( ! TabVal = t.Cells(x,y).Value ) Then TabVal=""`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that syntax?

Comment: This is usual syntax I use in some prog languages, means try to assign cell value to TabVal variable (here fn return reference), if successful the value is assigned, if this assignment is not successful (therefore negation !) then assign TabVal other value (here "")

Comment: You could use `IsError` and `Application.Match` as noted previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, an approach using `Application.Match` and `IsError`:

```
Public Function TabVal(ByVal t As Range, ByVal r As Range, ByVal c As Range) As Variant
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant

    x = Application.Match(r.Cells(1, 1).Value, t.Columns(1), 0)
    y = Application.Match(c.Cells(1, 1).Value, t.Rows(1), 0)

    If IsError(x) Or IsError(y) Then
        TabVal = vbNullString
    Else
        TabVal = t.Cells(x, y).Value
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: That's it, I simply don't like interrupt programming with GoTo errorhandler label. I preferer IF structures.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
Public Function TabVal(ByVal t As Range, ByVal r As Range, ByVal c As Range)
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each rng In t.Columns(1).Cells
        If rng = r Then
            x = rng.Row
            Exit For
        End If
        
    Next rng
    For Each rng In t.Rows(1).Cells
        If rng = c Then
            y = rng.Column
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rng
    
    If IsEmpty(x) Or IsEmpty(y) Then
    Else
        TabVal = Cells(x, y).Value
    End If
End Function
```